# Recycling parent as child in tbb

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I and want to parallelise a seemingly straightforward problem using `tbb::task`s. My tasks can be split into sub-tasks, the number of which cannot be chosen, but is determined by the state of the task (not known in advance). As a parent task does not require the results of its sub-tasks, I'd like to recycle the parent as its child. I couldn't find a good working example of this in the online documentation or examples, hence my question here. My current idea is to code along these lines:

```
struct my_task : tbb::task {
  typedef implementation_defined task_data;
  task_data DATA;
  my_task(task_data const&data) : DATA(data) {}
  void reset_state(task_data const&data) { DATA=data; }
  bool is_small() const;
  void serial_execution();
  bool has_more_sub_tasks() const;
  task_data parameters_for_next_sub_task();
  tbb::task*execute()
  {
    if(is_small()) {
      serial_execution();
      return nullptr;
    }
    tbb::empty_task&Continuation = allocate_continuation();     // <-- correct?
    task_data first_sub_task = parameters_for_next_sub_task();
    int sub_task_counter = 1;
    tbb::task_list further_sub_tasks;
    for(; has_more_sub_tasks(); ++sub_task_counter)
        further_sub_tasks.push_back(*new(Continuation.allocate_child())
                                     my_task(parameters_for_next_sub_task());
    Continuation.set_ref_count(sub_task_counter);               // <-- correct?
    spawn(further_sub_tasks);
    recycle_as_child_of(Continuation);                          // <-- correct?
    reset_state(first_sub_task);                                // change state
    return this;                                                // <-- correct?
  }
};

my_task*root_task = new(tbb::task::allocate_root())
                    my_task(parameters_for_root_task());
tbb::task::spawn_root_and_wait(*root_task);
```

Is this a correct and/or the best way to do this? (note that in my code above the empty continuation task is neither spawned nor returned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that creates the continuation should be:

> tbb::empty_task&Continuation = *new( allocate_continuation() ) tbb::empty_task;

The logic between set_ref_count and reset_state looks correct.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I noticed that you have interest in voronoi diagrams. I recently want to use voronoi partition in 2D and 3D for numerical work. I was wondering whether there are publically available efficient method to compute the voronoi cell for a given generator point without computing the whole voronoi diagram?

Comment: Computing a single Voronoi cell among N points takes Theta(N lg N) time in the worst case, and Theta(N) time in the average case, so there is only a Theta(lg N) savings for computing only a single cell.  Nonetheless, I wrote the single-cell algorithm for Voromoeba to detect "collisions".  If you are interested in further discussion or a copy of the code, please send me email via Arch.D.Robison {at} gmail.com .